# Return generic on a function without knowing for the specific parameters of it (the generic)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm stuck on a type definition for a function that accepts a generic that contains a discriminator.

What I need is to ensure that a function always return `MyType`, doesn't matter the specifics of the types inside the generic BUT I would like this to be "infered". E.g. that I don't have to write the specific `MyType` that I'm returning as is going to "merge" (even replace) return values

For example, here I'm receiving a type with 3 `MyType` related types, but only returning 2.

```js
interface MyType <Tag, Type> {
    tag: Tag;
    value: Type;
}

type SampleInputType = MyType<'a number', number> | MyType<'a string', string> | MyType<'foo', boolean>;

const sampleInputValue: SampleInputType = {
    tag: 'a number',
    value: 10
};

// Ideally would like to accept any MyType<W, X> and return any MyType<Y, Z>
// But not MyType<any, any>
// Would be fine with only the return type
const myFunction = (input) => {
    if (input.tag === 'a number') {
        return {
            tag: 'foo',
            value: true
        };
    } else {
        return {
            // Sample of type mistaked i would like to avoid, as this convert the return value to any silently
            tagx: 'a number', // This should be a compiler error
            value: 10
        }
    }
};


// Sample output type
type SampleOutputType = MyType<'a number', number> | MyType<'foo', boolean>;

// myVal only posibilities should only be MyType<'a number', number> and MyType<'foo', boolean>
const myVal = myFunction(sampleInputValue);

if (myVal.tag === 'foo') {
    const b: boolean = myVal.value; // this is any :/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if the discriminator's value is always of a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) then you should probably [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) the corresponding parameter to `string` so the compiler will infer this and catch more errors:

```
interface MyType<T extends string, V> {
    tag: T;
    value: V;
}
```

Probably the easiest way to tell the compiler that you are returning a valid `MyType<T, V>` without actually having to specify the generics is to use a helper function like this:

```
const myType = <T extends string, U>(x: MyType<T, U>) => x;
```

This is just an identity function at runtime (for all `x`, `myType(x)` is just `x`), but it will enforce the constraint you care about.  Then, inside your implementation of `myFunction`, pass your return value through `myType()`:

```
const myFunction = (input: MyType<string, unknown>)=> {
    if (input.tag === 'a number') {
        return myType({
            tag: 'foo',
            value: true
        });
    } else {
        return myType({
            tagx: 'a number', // error!
        //  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        //  Object literal may only specify known properties, 
        //  but 'tagx' does not exist in type 'MyType<string, unknown>'. 
        //  Did you mean to write 'tag'?
            value: 10
        });
    }
};
```

Note that the input type is `MyType<string, unknown>`, and I had to write that out.  I assume that's okay as you mentioned in the question; if not, all I can imagine doing here is possibly giving `MyType`'s generic parameters some [defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) so that you can write `MyType` to mean `MyType<string, unknown>`.  Moving on, though:

Hey, you got the error you wanted with `tagx`.  Once you fix it, the compiler sees `myFunction()` as being the following type:

```
const myFunction: (input: MyType<string, unknown>) => 
  MyType<"foo", boolean> | MyType<"a number", number>
```

So it infers that the return is a discriminated union, meaning you can do the sort of control-flow analysis test you want now:

```
if (myVal.tag === 'foo') {
    const b = myVal.value; // b is boolean
} else {
    myVal.value.toFixed(2); // myVal.value is number
}
```

---

UPDATE: if you want the specification of "I'd like the function to return some `MyType<?,?>`" to happen up at the function level instead of in the values being returned, you can use a different helper function, like this:

```
const myTypeReturner = <I extends any[], M extends MyType<string, unknown>>(
    x: (...args: I) => M) => x;
```

And then pass your whole `myFunction` implementation into it:

```
const myFunction2 = myTypeReturner(
    (input: MyType<string, unknown>) => { // error!
//  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Type '{ tagx: string; value: number; tag?: undefined; }' 
//  is not assignable to type 'MyType<string, unknown>'
        if (input.tag === 'a number') {
            return {
                tag: 'foo',
                value: true
            };
        } else {
            return {
                tagx: 'a number',
                value: 10
            };
        }
    });
```

This gives you an error, too... but it's unfortunately far away from the line which is "the problem" in your opinion.  The compiler says "I don't like this function", not "I don't like a particular line in the function".  So that's why I prefer the method I outlined above.  But either way works.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFkCeAVTAHKAHm1SgA9owATAZ1RohnAHMAaVANQD5UBvYVINQQEzAFypsAbgFCAbggA2AVygSOMgL7BgEfGgDKCALZ5FUAJJg8yiLgKoAvLMFZ7RAOQJUYZcYBGsB7svgGwPAA+GDj6hF70jCzBCUxgzJHR7nFwAPY5yf555ghgXDLASDlgDPQmZpbWthxKqhJGpuZWNnb6TnwuwqIS8aGBMMEDCipqqACMAAzAmuWV1RCoxjEOjqjEpBRQ1HQMqWycXAAUZBJusdjs3ACUTjxkK1U1mwBCCFQAYsowEgICAqn0LuBujctkQTix2ICANZgHIAd1Kz0cPH4QlQIDgqAhjQgADoRMwnI4diM-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-o+slKWpWlyWJWW7gmrwSHGm+UioEeEjgTAhXkruEiAlQUBwOAUBUIVmg1plgito26wIDQNAgMwYAIP45irh2DhdjCvYae+g6fqUHjOn+QWkuSIG0T49HjJBTGoNBOoIUxNEeKhjFbfILFSjhTHLKeKpqv0W07Zye1UUawx0WaaEncx0ysYsW1Xbh+EcRU9k3oCLlVB5OxeQQPkwf5i0ha+k3hTNXBWRqC0AUtwFUqBa3vZtYoPeRBCUftQwoXkH1UcV51QKeHFKjdxGIcT0NQGTz0U6adLHTTZ1sWKeFKksQM6K67T1ImtjdCN9N6A4kvmAGMu2NlOxqXEb28-jYwZJrh1U+whQ5MUpTlK6mzNIoiZgMmqB4DkPX+CAkaFscAAWC6KLOSYJoEL49jzDG6+EUnUIHnhHeWRTLqUwPXlbsZQ5gzn3u5Fw0HUnTEtbqhAwtSeKEBFK45T+SE4IPHrP4nmYNbJJHoVrq1+1Jtm0szN3UIReN5hZI5H8IBkA1FxuQqMVcg3R54nQpVLEAA)

Comment: Thanks you. My question is not specific enough, but I wanted to enforce this at the function level e.g. `const myFunction: (something) => OneOf MyType` or `const myFunction = () : OneOfMyType ..`. I suppose that's not possible yet? Other problem is that similar applies for the input value, the way is set with `MyType<string, unknown>` makes so that "tag" is no longer "a number" | "foo" | "a string" inside the function, but "string".

Comment: For the input I have no real idea how you expect the compiler to know it without annotating it yourself.  You can write `(input: SampleInputType) => ...` for example, and then the compiler will know that `tag` is `"a number" | "foo" | "a string"`.  I mean, that's not really inferrable, is it?  I certainly can't infer it by looking at the function implementation.

Comment: Updated the answer for a different way to do it closer to "the function level".  No, there's no way to annotate a generic type without specifying its generics, any kind of `OneOf`, without direct support for [existential types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) or maybe [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574).  Helper functions are the closest you can get there, in my experience.

Comment: `For the input I have no real idea how you expect the compiler to know it without annotating it yourself` Sorry, you are right. I have the type already, I just wanted to make sure it is of type `MyType<string, something>`, but that's not really important.